# The SQL command requires 1 parameter, but the parameter mapping only has 0 when using OLE DB Source and SQL Command from Variable, SSIS

Tags: parameters, ssis, oledb, oledbcommand

I'm creating a SSIS package where I have an `Expression Task` connected to a `Data Flow Task` in the `Control Flow`.

The Expression task is:

`@[User::DateVariable] = year(DATEADD("day", - @[$Project::DaystoReload] , getdate() ))*10000`

The `OLE DB Source` uses a `SQL Command from Variable` as the source, and it has the appearence:

"SELECT Country, Population, Region, Date

INNER JOIN [" + @[User::DatabaseName] + "].[dbo].[Country]
where Date >= ?"

User::DatabaseName has `EvaluateAsExpression` set to TRUE, it is a string. `DateVariable` which is created from the Expression Task Before the Data Flow task is of data type `Int32`.

When I use the Query in SSMS, and I use the value which Expression Task evaluates `DateVariable` to "hard-coded" then I get the correct output, but in SSIS I get the error that

> The SQL command requires 1 parameter, but the parameter mapping only has 0

I've been trying to Google this issue, but I haven't found a solution for when the `OLE DB Source` uses `SQL Command from Variable`, but rather just the `SQL command` in which you have a option called `Parameter` which you can map to the parameter. I haven't found such an option using Sql command from variable.

Does anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: Since your variable is already populated before, why dont you just not write Where Date >= " +@User::DATEVARIABLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant pass parameters inside OLEDB SOURCE with SQL Command via Variable.

You have to pass a variable instead. And since you already stored a value inside your Date Variable, it should be possible to use

So your SQL Variable should be like this:

```
"SELECT Country, Population, Region, Date

INNER JOIN [" + @[User::DatabaseName] + "].[dbo].[Country]  where date >= "+  (DT_WSTR,20)@[User::Date]
```

Comment: I've tried that as well. My date is of data type `int` in SQL Server, and the corresponding variable in SSIS has data type `int32`. I've had difficulties with using ´User::DateVariable` inside the SQL Query variable. I've tried using `" + @[User::DateVariable] + "`, `+ @[User::DateVariable] +`, but it has led to errors which seem to indicate that using `+` wont work with integer variables. I'm gonna try your solution, and see where I fail with my integer variable.

Comment: Like i wrote. You should cast it by writing (DT_WSTR,20)VARIABLE - I just tested it myself and it works fine with an int variable

Comment: I saw that you had that difference as well, and I tested it and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case when you importing data from excel using SSIS ,then you might face this type of issue.The solution of this issue is given below:

When I'm using in excel connection manager by SQL query in SQL Command tab:

SELECT F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, F10, F11, F12, F13, F14, F15, F16, F17, F18 FROM [Data$A2:P]

Then there was an error that required 2 parameters but mapping is 0.
When I checked then found that we are taking data for 18 columns but in sheet mention only A2:P which means 16 columns dat## Heading ##a only .
Either change the range From [Data$A2:R] or just take the column till F16.
This issue is resolved now,please verify by doing this.